# Inline Sum() vs query Sum() vs Where on a List<T> object

Tags: c#

Just after a bit of feed back or peoples ideas on which practice is best.

I currently have a method but am unsure of the best way to approach it from a readability point of view or even from best practices point of view.  Or perhaps it doesn't really matter at all and they are all fine?

My three options I explored were:

1)

```
function double GetObjectArea(CustomObject obj, CustomEnum source)
{
   return obj.ListOfApplications.Sum(p => p.Source == source ? object.Area : 0);
}
```

2)

```
function double GetObjectArea(CustomObject obj, CustomEnum source)
{
   var query = from record in obj.ListOfApplications
               where record.Source == source
               select object.Area

   return query.Sum();
}
```

3)

```
function double GetObjectArea(CustomObject obj, CustomEnum source)
{
   return obj.ListOfApplications.Where(p.Source == source).Sum(object.Area);
}
```

Comment: For compactness, I would use the third method, but for clarity, I would probably use the second one. Plus, I personally like queries over the function call chains for readability.

Comment: I agree Nick, I prefer queries but think maybe in this case when it's a simple chain it, I'm leaning towards option 3 being the better option.

Comment: I'm going to buck the trend and like the first one over the others.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer ha really Jesse. That was my very fist way I did it but then started thinking that there may be better ways hence this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with the third, with the second as secondary choice.

The first mixes addition logic and comparison logic: it's not immediately clear that the zero is meant to exclude those objects, as opposed to giving a default for `object.Area`.

The second is better, but it hides the point behind a lot of unnecessary syntax.  The fact that you're working on `object.Area` and not `record.Area` gets lost.

The third is even better.  It can be conveniently read left-to-right, and all the information is grouped near what we're doing (condition is after the where, sum elements are after the sum).

Personally, I would use

```
double GetObjectArea(CustomObject obj, CustomEnum source)
{
   return obj.ListOfApplications.Count(p => p.Source == source) * object.Area;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anton.  I like your option you provided in seperating the Area out.  In general I like option 2 myself where I can but agree option 3 probably makes better sense in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I like the third one since it's really clear what it's doing.
Here's a question that I'd like to ask:
Do you really need to encapsulate this logic in a method ? do you really need to use it in different places of your code ? if the answer is yes then you are doing DRY and if it's no it's a sign of YAGNI. You can filter your query whenever you need it without using (and adding) a function.
If you still need to introduce a new function I suggest you use a more meaningful definition for it something like ( I use an extension method to make it more readable but it might be a function of CustomObject itself)

```
double GetSumOfAreaWhereSourceIs(this CustomObject obj,CustomEnum source);
```

then you will have :

```
var sum=myObj.GetSumOfAreaWhereSourceIs(mySource);
```

which is more readable than

```
var sum=GetObjectArea(myObj,mySource);
```

in my opinion.

Comment: I was making the same call in about 6 lines in a row to set some properties and the readability was getting a bit lost so having the method made it a bit easier to read.  An extension  method might be overkill in this particular situation but I agree that they do make for easier reading as well.